# Why I cannot use the natural logarithm function with the data set?

Tags: r, error-handling, nan, finance, logarithm

I've got a code that works with the Data Set. I found out that it doesn't want to work with the ln(x) function. The data set can be found [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1632960000&period2=1647907200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true).

```
LY <- ln(Apple$Close - Apple$Open)
```

> Warning in log(x) : NaNs produced

Could you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: `Apple$Close - Apple$Open` can be zero or negative - in which case log is not defined

Comment: But how to fix it though? I need to find the natural logarithm of them

Comment: where did you find the `ln()` function? It's not part of base R ...

Comment: SciViews package

Answer (score 3):

Since stocks can go down as well as up (unfortunately), `Close` can be less than `Open` and `Close - Open` can be negative. It just doesn't make sense to take the natural log of a negative number; it's like dividing by zero, or more precisely like taking the square root of a negative number.

Actually, you *can* take the logarithm of a *complex number with a negative real part*:

```r
log(as.complex(-1))
## [1] 0+3.141593i
```

... but "i times pi" is probably not a very useful result for further data analysis ...

(in R, `log()` takes the natural logarithm. While the `SciViews` package provides `ln()` as a synonym, you might as well just get used to using `log()` - this is a convention across most programming languages ...)

Depending on what you're trying to do, the logarithm of the close/open **ratio** can be a useful value (`log(Close/Open)`): this is negative when `Close < Open`, positive when `Close > Open`). As @jpiversen points out, this is called the *logarithmic return*; as @KarelZe points out, `log(Close/Open)` is mathematically equivalent to `log(Close) - log(Open)` (which might be what your professor wanted ... ???)

Comment: The professor gave us this formula and we must use it, and I clearly don't understand how to place it in the code

Comment: You should probably ask the professor for clarification then ... taking the log of the *ratio* (`log(close/open)`) would be a sensible thing to do ...

Comment: @BenBolker True. There might be a missunderstanding regarding logarithmic laws $\log(close/open) = \log(close)-\log(open)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for logarithmic return? In that case the formula would be:

```r
log(Apple$Close / Apple$Open)
```

Since `A / B` for two positive values is always positive, this will not create `NaN`s.